# Location of wifi password/ssid in OpenELEC (Rasperry Pi version)

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, openelec

Where OpenELEC stores wifi password/ssid? Is it protected somehow or anybody who can get my SD card can read it?

I unpacked my OpenELEC's squashfs image so I can browse freely inside its contents but I can't find the location where my password/ssid are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a [forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=56386):

> I noticed when using Openelec v3.2, RPi store the user's SSID and Wifi Passphrase in unencrypted plaintext in the 'settings' file located under 'addon_data>os.openelec.settings'.

I don't use OpenELEC, so I can't check if that's the case, but there has to be a way to decrypt the passphrase so the system can use it to authenticate itself with the WiFi access point. An attacker could extract and decrypt the passphrase in the same way if they gained access to your SD card.